# Safe to remove piezo-buzzer from this PCB?

Tags: piezo-buzzer

[image: Buzzer 1] [image: Buzzer 2]

*(Click on images for larger view.)*

The AC indoor unit I own has an 85dB, 2kHz piezo-buzzer on the PCB. I find it unnecessarily loud, so after coming across [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/41806/81707) I filled its hole with blu-tack. This muffled the sound it produces, but not as much as I expected. I'm willing to try hot glue in the future.

What I'd like to know is whether it is safe to remove the piezo-buzzer from the circuit. If not, what can I replace it with?

[image: Buzzer 5] [image: Buzzer 6]

*(Click on images for larger view.)*

The schematic diagram and PCB diagram above are taken from the unit's service manual (the location of the buzzer is `BZ61`). Bearing in mind I don't have much of a background in electronics, and have little experience fiddling with PCB's (sorry!), is there anything useful I can safely assume from these diagrams?

Comment: Just clipping the metal wire leading into the buzzer shown in the top picture should do. Then bend the leads away. This way you can re-hook it up if necessary. No harm will be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely remove it without any substitution. The Transistors are fully biased in the system by resistors already.

In fact, they have slightly over-engineered it, if you ask me, but these days I'd say I'm pleasantly surprised by such things.

You/it should not even notice the removal by a change in power required for the buzzer circuit to any noticeable extend.

Comment: Wow ... lets add a few more transistors - just in case. :)

Comment: @brhans certainly the first time I saw an appliance use a piezo with a balanced amplifier layout, heck I've seen shoddier speaker set-ups.